# Open in new tab link in SO blog is not open in the new tab

Tags: bug, status-declined, blog

The open in new tab link for the **Developer Hiring Blog** in the [Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) is not open in the new tab.

Same kind of issue is in Email Settings too, [reported in MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304047/312043)

[image]

Comment: Not a bug, as stated in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The icon doesn't mean the link will open in a new tab. It means the link points to a different domain than the one your currently on.

When clicking on that link, you are leaving `stackoverflow.blog` and navigating to `www.stackoverflowbusiness.com`.

Comment: I feel this icons purpose/representation is very opinionated topic as to me, that icon represents not only a url to a different domain, but also to a new tab. The reason I say this is because there are plenty of SO & non-SO links on here that don't use that icon.

Comment: @ProEvilz: Since when can icons have an opinion?

Comment: I'm sure you knew what I meant by that.

Comment: Websites have _no realistic control_ over where the clicked link opens. Never assume a clicked link opens in a new tab. If you want it to open in a new tab, just middle-click / ctrl-click it.

Comment: @ProEvilz I think the icon seems to be a new "feature" (personally hadn't seen it before), and they didn't retroactively add the icon to all existing links. But that's just guesswork, of course.

Comment: I have to disagree here being the icon is called `glyphicon-new-window` and looking at what the [UX site thinks](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55419/how-to-indicate-this-button-link-opens-a-new-tab)

Comment: @George because people have never misused a glyphicon before, right? :) And at least one commenter on the link mentions its alternate 'external site' meaning.

Comment: @Stijn Fair point, I thought the kettlebell one was a thumb for a while, but I'd argue that this is more seen as a link to a new tab rather than a link to an external site, which is normally done via a new window/tab anyway.